# Textview below each image in a galleryview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, galleryview

In my application i am using some 5 galleryview to display the image, done correctly,i can able to populate the image correctly.Now i want to add textview below each image.

I want gallery view like this:

```
image1    Image2    Image3  image4
                                             -------->Galleryview1

text1     text2      text3   text4

------------------------------------------
image1    image2    image3    image4

                                             --------->Galleryview2
text1     text2      text3    text4
```

**My code:**

Adapter code:

```
public class GalleryviewAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{      

    static final String URL="http://aaaa/home.xml";


    public static GalleryviewAdapter instance=new GalleryviewAdapter();
    public static GalleryviewAdapter getInstance()
       {
           return instance;
       }
       Context context;        
       GalleryviewAdapter()
       {
           System.out.println("Inside cons");
           getelement();
//         getelementindia();
       }
//     String[] itemsArray = 
//         {
//       "SUN","MON", "TUS", "WED", "THU", "FRI", "SAT"
//         };

//     MyAdapter(Context c)
//     {
//      context = c;
//     }

       private Activity activity;  
       private  LayoutInflater inflater=null; 
       public void ImageAdapter(Activity a) 
       {   
           activity = a;  
                inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService
                        (Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);         
        } 

    String imageurl[]= {};//new String[5];
//    String imageurlindia[]={};
    public void getelement()
    {
        System.out.println("Inside getelement");
//     String[] itemsarray={};
//     ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
//     ArrayList<String> menuItems = new ArrayList<String>();
       TaplistingParser parser = new TaplistingParser();
       String xml= parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL);
       Document doc=parser.getDomElement(xml);        
//       System.out.println("sssss="+doc);
       NodeList nl=doc.getElementsByTagName("article");
       imageurl = new String[nl.getLength()];
       System.out.println("len="+nl.getLength());
       for(int i=0; i < nl.getLength(); i++ )
       {
//         System.out.println("Inside for");
//          HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
//          map.put("SectionName", parser.getValue(e, "sectionname"));
//          System.out.println("b4 items="+parser.getValue(e, "sectionname"));
//          itemsarray[i] = parser.getValue(e, "sectionname");
//          System.out.println("items="+itemsarray[i]);
        imageurl[i]=parser.getValue(e, "kickerimage");
//          menuItems.add(parser.getValue(e, "sectionname"));
//      menuItems.add(parser.getValue(e, "sectionname"));
//       System.out.println("menu="+menuItems);

       }    
//      String[] itemsarray = menuItems.toArray(new String[menuItems.size()]); 

//       String[] itemsarray = new String[menuItems.size()];
//       itemsarray=menuItems.toArray(itemsarray);
////       for(int j= 0;j < itemsarray.length;j++ )
////       {
////           Log.d("string is",(itemsarray[j]));
////       }
//      return itemsarray;
    }





      public int getCount() 
      {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return imageurl.length;
      }


      public Object getItem(int position) 
      {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       return imageurl[position];
      }


      public long getItemId(int position) 
      {

       return position;
      }

      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
      {

//        System.out.println("sssssssss="+imageurl[position]);
//          View vi=convertView;   
//          ViewHolder holder;   
//          if(convertView==null)
//          {  
//              vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main, null); 
//              holder=new ViewHolder();  
//              holder.text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.Txt01);  
//              holder.image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageview1);   
//              vi.setTag(holder);   
//          }

       Bitmap bitmap=DownloadImage(imageurl[position]);
       View rowView = LayoutInflater
         .from(parent.getContext())
         .inflate(R.layout.main, null);
//     
       ImageView imgview=(ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageview1);     
       imgview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


//     
//     ImageView imgviewindia=(ImageView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageviewindia);
//     imgviewindia.setImageBitmap(bitmap);


//     TextView listTextView = (TextView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.);
//     listTextView.setText(getelement()[position]);           
       return rowView;
      } 

      private Bitmap DownloadImage(String URL)
        {        
//          System.out.println("image inside="+URL);
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            InputStream in = null;        
            try
            {
                in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
//          System.out.println("image last");
            return bitmap;                
        }
        private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString)
                throws IOException
                {
                    InputStream in = null;
                    int response = -1;

                    URL url = new URL(urlString);
                    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

                    if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))                    
                        throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");                   
                    try{
                        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
                        httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
                        httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
                        httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
                        httpConn.connect();

                        response = httpConn.getResponseCode();                
                        if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) 
                        {
                            in = httpConn.getInputStream();                                
                        }                    
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw new IOException("Error connecting");            
                    }
                    return in;    
        }
      }
//  }
```

Main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"        
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp" 
        />
      <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Txt01" />

</LinearLayout>
```

My main activitycode:

```
public class NewspapperActivity extends Activity 
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Context ctx;

    static final String URLHeading = "http://aaaaaa.in/cccccc.xml";
    String[] headingurl=new String[20];
//    ListViewwithimageAdapter adapter;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.galleryview);        
//        ArrayList<String>item = new ArrayList<String>();

        Heading parser = new Heading();       
        String xmldata = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URLHeading);

        Document domelement = parser.getDomElement(xmldata);

        NodeList node = domelement.getElementsByTagName("item");

//        int i ;

        TextView txt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Text01);
        TextView txt2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Text02);
        TextView txt3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Text03);
        TextView txt4 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Text04);
        TextView txt5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Text05);


//        glly.setAdapter(adapter);
//        System.out.println("prakash4");
//        for(i=0 ; i < node.getLength();i++)
//        {
            Element e0 = (Element) node.item(0);
            txt1.setText(parser.getValue(e0, "sectionname"));

            Element e1 = (Element) node.item(1);
            txt2.setText(parser.getValue(e1, "sectionname"));

            Element e2 = (Element) node.item(2);
            txt3.setText(parser.getValue(e2, "sectionname"));

            Element e3 = (Element) node.item(3);
            txt4.setText(parser.getValue(e3, "sectionname"));

            Element e4 = (Element) node.item(4);
            txt5.setText(parser.getValue(e4, "sectionname"));

            Gallery glly= (Gallery)findViewById(R.id.Gallery01);
            Gallery glly2= (Gallery)findViewById(R.id.Gallery02);
            Gallery glly3= (Gallery)findViewById(R.id.Gallery03);
            Gallery glly4= (Gallery)findViewById(R.id.Gallery04);
            Gallery glly5= (Gallery)findViewById(R.id.Gallery05);
//          GridView gv = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.grid);

//          ListViewwithimageAdapter adapter = ListViewwithimageAdapter.getInstance();
            GalleryviewAdapter adapter=GalleryviewAdapter.getInstance();
            glly.setAdapter(adapter);    
            glly.setSelection(1);
            glly2.setAdapter(adapter);
            glly2.setSelection(1);
            glly3.setAdapter(adapter);
            glly3.setSelection(1);
            glly4.setAdapter(adapter);
            glly4.setSelection(1);
            glly5.setAdapter(adapter);
            glly5.setSelection(1);
//          item.add(parser.getValue(e, "sectionname"));
//        }
//        gv.setAdapter(new GridviewImageAdapter(this));

    }
```

}

I am new to this ..Please help me.Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Use below xml code instead of your xml code, it will solve your problem and if you have any problem regarding that then tell me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview1"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" 
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Txt01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageview1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Dipak" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @Subburaj Post your complete java and xml code so i can understand where is the problem?

Comment: @Subburaj If possible send me your complete code so i will change in this code and resend to you.

Comment: IGP...I have posted my complete code ...see i have 1 main activity(That is my main activity i have posted),,2nd id the adapter class(i have posted),3rd id my XML (i have posted)..so what u r expecting????

Comment: @Subburaj you are telling me the text is displaying but image is not displaying in first comment but in your code you are commenting textview declaration in getview() method so how can you say the text is displaying?, sorry for my bad English communication.

Comment: IGP in your code defining textview u have set the textview Text as android:text="Dipak" ...This text is displaying...Actually the image should display and below that your your textview android:text="Dipak" ..should display..But now only the Dipak is showing...not the image..i think i explained clearly..